# Clickable TextViews in Staggered GridView

Tags: android, gridview, clickable, staggered-gridview, flipboard

I am trying to show dynamic list of strings in GridView. Every word will be clickable and can be selected or deselected. I am attaching a screenshot of Flipboard as I want exactly the same functionality.

[image]

Please help me to find out the same functionality to be implemeted in my app.

Comment: did you try anything ... show some code

Comment: how did you implement this functionality?

Comment: can you share how did you implement this?

Comment: was this implemented ? Can you share if it is

Comment: @user1288005 How the above layout will be shown in recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way and without any external libraries you can use native components **Gridview** or **recyclerview** with GridLayoutManager

Follow this steps :

1 - Design your row item it's means the click-able labels in separated xml file.

2 - Create your adapter class to inflate view, show the data and handle clicks.

3- attach adapter to *gridview* or *recyclerview*.

And her is example for [RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/) and other one for [Gridview](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/adroitandroid/ChipCloud) or [this](https://github.com/robertlevonyan/materialChipView) libraries to do this type of functionality